# Bottom tabBar hide

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi 
In my application i am using TabBar.At first when I call loginControl,I am hiding the tab bar using `[login hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES];` now if login is a success then I show detailViewController but I do not see the TabBar even after setting `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to `NO`.
what's the problem... can any one help me??

Comment: Give us some code, It could be that you are pushing your detailView on top of the tabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need your login view controller anymore you can pop it before push the second. This will do the work but there is strange animation in the back button. It still a solution :)

```
[navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Edit:

Try this....

```
loginSuccessController *login = [[loginSuccessController alloc] initWithNibName:@"loginSuccessController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:login animated:YES];
```

Comment: hey Jorge,this is not possible because popViewControlerAnimated call first .. so no effect on pushViewController...

Answer (score 0):

can you try `[self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:NO];` in your loginsuccesscontroller's viewwillappear or viewdidload

Answer (score 0):

Use this method for hide and show tabbar :)

```
-(void)makeTabBarHidden:(BOOL)hide
{ 

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = self.tabBarController; 

    if ( hide == tabBarController.tabBar.hidden ) { 
        return; 
    } 


    UIView *contentView; 

    if ( [[tabBarController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]] ) { 
        contentView = [tabBarController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1]; 
    } else { 
        contentView = [tabBarController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]; 
    } 

    if (hide) { 
        contentView.frame = tabBarController.view.bounds; 
    } 
    else { 
        contentView.frame = CGRectMake(tabBarController.view.bounds.origin.x, 
                                       tabBarController.view.bounds.origin.y, 
                                       tabBarController.view.bounds.size.width, 
                                       tabBarController.view.bounds.size.height - tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height); 
    } 

    tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = hide; 
}
```